# How to redirect a make program's stdout when using it in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, makeprg

I use Google `closure-compiler` to check syntax errors in a JS file, the problem is that if there is no error it gives the source of the file to its STDOUT and with the default settings this counts as an error and clutters the quickfix window.

In Bash I can do this: `$closure-compiler foo.js 1>/dev/null` and then it gives only errors, otherwise nothing.

But is it possible to specify this command to the Vim `makeprg` option? I tried many ways to no avail, for instance this:

```
set makeprg = closure-compiler\ %\ 1>/dev/null
```

doesn't return STDERR as well as STDOUT.

This:

```
 set makeprg = closure-compiler\ %\ '1>/dev/null'
```

treats `1>/dev/null` as a file name, etc.

I know I can create a Bash-script but is it possible to do it only in `vimrc`?

Thank you.

I suppose there is no way for this without the bash-script, since errors are STDERR only for `closure-compiler`, but Vim (I suppose) uses the terminal program and for it STDERR of `closure-compiler` becomes STDOUT, so that Vim doesn't receive STDERR in this case but STDOUT from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I did it with the help of the `eval` bash program:

```
set makeprg=eval\ 'closure-compiler\ %\ 1>/dev/null'
```

This approach doesn't require a separate bash script, so `make` can be called independently of the cwd. The minus of this solution is that it can safely be used only in terminal with the bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

Vim includes a feature called [`quickfix`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix) that consists of a way of compiling source code using an external program and processing its output. Any failures are loaded as an iterable list into the [`quickfix-window`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window).

You can also check the vim help pages for [`errorformat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat), which defines filtering expressions to identify error messages in the output of [`'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27) (the option that determines what external program is used to process the code).

Alternatively, simply install [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic). I can see a reference to Closure Compiler [here](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic-checkers.txt), so it should be supported.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I really appreciate this, but your answer, actually, doesn't answer the question. I know about the `quickfix` feature, that is why I'm asking about the redirection for the `makeprg` program, because I use quickfix.

Comment: And I don't want to mess with the `errorformat` option, since it's kinda complex and closure-compiler already gives error messages in a format, which is understood by Vim out of the box, so I'm sure there is no need to change errorformat. I want something simpler, even simpler that an unnecessary plugin, why to install it just for one feature, which could be achieved with a simpler approach, like using the eval command or a bash script.